# wmctrl showing and hiding tray programs

Tags: wmctrl, tray

Hello there im trying to make my onboard hide/show with a keyboard shortcut (i know ironic, please don't ask why) however i couldn't find a way to do it in their manual, it only shows programs that are windowed programs that can go to tray however onboard is completely tray program it doesn't have a window name, is it possible to work around that with wmctrl?

Im using linux mint with cinnamon btw if that changes anything.

Comment: I had that problem before and IIRC answer is no - hidden windows are not shown by `wmctrl`.

Comment: What should i use then?